# How do I make the header and naviation bar both fixed at the top when scrolling down

Tags: jquery, css, navigationbar

How can I make the Navigation bar goes below and close to the Header bar when scrolling down? Currently navigation bar covers the header. This is what I achieved so far, please check [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ks1chdab/3/) and help me fix it.

Here is my css i have up to now on the header bar:

```
position: fixed;
width:100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: chartreuse;
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use only CSS `postion: sticky` (instead of js).
e.g.:

```
.element {
   position: sticky;
   top: 10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ks1chdab/9/)

[MDN - postion - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

[Can I use - browsers support for postion: sticky](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)

Comment: Thanks that was simple, however how can I apply this solution [in this website](https://boundless-theme-apparel.myshopify.com/collections/man) I mean making both header and navigation bar sticky and navigation bar goes below and close to the Header bar when scrolling down?

Comment: Yes, you can. Please take a look at this example. https://jsfiddle.net/ks1chdab/26/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/ks1chdab/4/

I just changed `top: 0;` in `#navbar.fixed` with `50px`:

```
#navbar.fixed {
    ...
    top: 50px;
    ...
}
```

```js
var stickyNavTop = $('#navbar').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {  
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyNavTop) {
        $('#navbar').addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
        $('#navbar').removeClass('fixed');
    }  
});
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body{
 min-height: 100%;
 background-color: #aaaabb;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: chartreuse;
    text-align: center;
}

#navbar{
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

#navbar.fixed{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    color: #000;
}

#navbar ul,
#footer ul {
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#navbar ul li,
#footer ul li{
 display: inline-block;
}

#navbar li a.nav-active{
 color: #1F2ED1;
}

#navbar ul li a,
#footer ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 8px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #cecece;
 display: block;
}

.body-wrapper{
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.section{
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header"><h2>HEADER IMAGE</h2></div>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/960/450" />
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#home-section" class="nav-active">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about-section">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#products-section">Products</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact-section">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="body-wrapper">
  <div id="home-section" class="section">
   <h3>Home heading</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="about-section" class="section">
   <h3>About heading</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="products-section" class="section">
   <h3>Products heading</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="contact-section" class="section">
   <h3>Contact heading</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
  <ul>
   <li>&#169; Test</li>
   <li><a href="">Terms</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Privacy</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks that was simple, however how can I apply this solution [in this website](https://boundless-theme-apparel.myshopify.com/collections/man) I mean making both header and navigation bar sticky and navigation bar goes below and close to the Header bar when scrolling down?

Comment: Sorry, that goes beyond the original question.

Comment: I wanted first to make an example in JSfiddle of the same issue I'm having on this theme. Then once I get a working solution, I will just apply it but looks like it didn't work. That's why I asked you take a look and see why it didn't work since I'm a newbie in web dev.